# Sending $_POST variables to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a simple drawing tool with JavaScript and I'm using PHP to generate a table which is used as a canvas. To enable customizing the dimensions I did this

```
$input = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($input == 'POST') {
    $width = (int) $_POST['width'];
    $height = (int) $_POST['height'];
}
```

But I also need to use these same values in JavaScript for creating a String that holds all coordinates for all colored table elements. Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT: Here is the JS function that needs the values.

```
        function constructCanvasString(){       

            var width = 128;
            var height = 64:

            var canvasString = width + ' ' + height + '\\n';
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    if (   $('#' + x + '-' + y).css('background-color') !== 'transparent' ) {
                        canvasString = canvasString + x + ' ' + y + ' ' + ($('#' + x + '-' + y).css('background-color')).replace(/\s/g, '') + '\\n';
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('canvas').value = canvasString;
        }
```

The function is called when a user clicks a button after the drawing has been drawn (when td elements have gained style attribute background-color)

Comment: At what point do you need to get the values with JavaScript?  Is this done via an asynchronous request?

Comment: can't you pass it to a js function while posting on the front end?

Comment: Are you posting to a php page and it's reloading, or are you doing it through ajax?

Comment: User goes to page, and can start drawing with default values 128 x 64 or can enter new values in HTML form which sends new values to the same page. The page sees and uses the POST values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access PHP variables in javascript this way:

```
    var width = "<?php echo $width ?>"
```

Comment: Are values remembered across two different PHP blocks on the same page?

Comment: This method should look for the last declaration of the PHP variable, anywhere on the page.